# Possible mistake in Derivation 4.13 from Classical Mechanics by Goldstein. Coordinates transformations, matrices

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems

> Suppose two successive coordinate rotations through angles $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ are carried out, equivalent to a single rotation through an angle $\Phi$. Show that $\Phi_1/2$, $\Phi_2/2$ and $\Phi/2$ can be considered as the sides of a spherical triangle with the angle opposite to $\Phi/2$  given by the angle between the two axes of rotation.

Applying the rule cosine in the spherical triangle mentioned, we have

$$\cos (\Phi/2) = \cos (\Phi_1/2) \cos (\Phi_2/2) + \sin (\Phi_1/2) \sin (\Phi_2/2) \cos(\alpha)$$

where $\alpha$ is the angle between the axes of rotation.

Now, let's think in the case that the two consecutive rotations are around the same axis, that is $\alpha = 0$. Also, let's consider an initial coordinate system where the $z$ axis is along the axis of rotation. Then, $\Phi = \Phi_1 + \Phi_2$, but the cosine rule give us

$$\cos (\Phi/2) = \cos (\Phi_1/2) \cos (\Phi_2/2) + \sin (\Phi_1/2) \sin (\Phi_2/2)$$.

$$\cos (\Phi/2) = \cos \left(\frac{\Phi_2}{2} -\frac{\Phi_1}{2} \right) = \cos \left(\frac{\Phi_2 -\Phi_1}{2} \right) $$

If $\Phi_1 = \Phi_2 = \pi / 2$, then we get $\cos(\Phi) = -1$ and $\cos(\Phi) = 1$

In view of the above, I conclude that the problem has an mistake.

Comment: *$''$Classical Mechanics$''$* by H.Goldstein-C.Poole-J.Safco, 3rd Edition, Chapter 4, Derivation 4.13, page 181.

Comment: May be you are right.  I think that we must correct to *$''$...with the angle opposite to $\Phi/2$  given by $\:(\pi-\alpha)\:$ where $\:\alpha\:$ the angle between the two axes of rotation.$''$*

Comment: By the way take a look at the spherical triangle $\texttt{DEF}$ in the Figure of my answer here : [Why is there this relationship between quaternions and Pauli matrices?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/271419/why-is-there-this-relationship-between-quaternions-and-pauli-matrices/272563#272563), replacing
$$
\alpha \rightarrow \Phi_1, \beta \rightarrow \Phi_2, \phi \rightarrow \Phi, \omega \rightarrow \alpha
$$

Comment: Then
$$\cos (\Phi/2) = \cos (\Phi_1/2) \cos (\Phi_2/2) \boldsymbol{-} \sin (\Phi_1/2) \sin (\Phi_2/2) \cos(\alpha)$$