# Rotation by 360°, spin-1/2 fermions and quaternions

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory, fermions, spinors, complex-numbers

Rotating a spin-1/2 fermion by 360° multiplies the quantum state by -1.

Representing a continuous 360° rotation as a quaternion is also a multiplication by -1.

Is there a relationship between these two? What is the correspondence?

Answer (score 0):

We know su(2) is isomorphic to unit quaternion, and the rotation group of spin-1/2 system is su(2) too.  So in fact they are the same thing.

In fact, we can use Pauli matrix. Let $i = - \mathrm{i}\sigma_x$, $j = - \mathrm{i}\sigma_y$, $k = - \mathrm{i}\sigma_z$. Then we found $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1$, and $a + bi + cj + dk$ is a representation of quaternion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [3D rotation group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group) $SO(3)$ has double cover
$$SPIN(3)~\cong~ SU(2)~\cong~ U(1,\mathbb{H}),$$ see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/271419/2451) Phys.SE post for details. In particular, the [fundamental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_representation) spin 1/2 [spinor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor) is indeed a [quaternionic/pseudoreal representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_representation) with vector space $$\mathbb{H}~\cong~ \mathbb{C}^2.$$