# ${\bf su}(2)$ generators in 1, 2 and 3 dimensional matrix representations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, lie-algebra

The ${\bf su}(2)$ Lie algebra in a representation $\bf R$ is defined by

$$[T^{a}_{\bf R},T^{b}_{\bf R}]=i\epsilon^{abc}T^{c}_{\bf R},$$

where $T^{a}_{\bf R}$ are the $3$ generators of the algebra.

In 2 dimensions, these generators are the Pauli matrices

$$T^{1}_{\bf 1} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad T^{2}_{\bf 1} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0 & -i\\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad
T^{3}_{\bf 1} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

In 3 dimensions, these generators are

$$T^{1}_{\bf 2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad T^{2}_{\bf 2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}0 & -i & 0\\ i & 0 & -i\\ 0 & i & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad
T^{3}_{\bf 2} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}.$$

---

1. How can you derive the generators in $2$ and $3$ dimensions?
2. What are the generators in $1$ dimension?

Comment: The 1-dimensional representation of the algebra is not faithful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using the ladder operators, as described e.g. in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_operator#Angular_momentum).
2. Hint: $1\times 1$ matrices commute.

Comment: I find that the $1$ dimensional generators are all $0$. Is this true?

Comment: @nightmarish How do you want nonzero traceless matrices to exist in one dimension?

Comment: It is not possible to have non-zero traceless matrices in one dimension!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

1. Construct the $2\times 2$ representation from first principles directly from the commutation relationships, as [I do here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/193048/26076). Clean up the $i$ factor to make them Hermitian rather than skew Hermitian;
2. Since the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is centerless, the adjoint representation is  an isomorphism ($\ker(\mathrm{ad}) = \mathscr{Z}$ is a fact you should remember). Moreover, the image of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ under $\mathrm{ad}$ gives you a $3\times 3$ representation because $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is three dimensional. Thus compute the images $\mathrm{ad}(i\,\sigma_j)$ of the matrices $\sigma_j$ in (1) under the adjoint representation and you're done for $3\times 3$ after adding the $i$ factor to make them Hermitian;
3. $1\times 1$ matrices can only represent the unique, one dimensional Lie algebra $(\mathbb{R},\,+)$, so, as noted elsewhere, "it can't be faithful".

The technique in (1) gives you representatives of *equivalence classes* of representations modulo similarity transformations, and an analysis of this technique shows that it is exhaustive, *i.e.* the equivalence class contains *all* possible solutions. Thus, the application of (3) will give you different matrices from the ones you cite, but which can be transformed into yours with the appropriate similarity transformation.