# Pauli matrices from anticommutator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

I want construct the Pauli matrices starting from $$\sigma_i=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
 c& d
\end{bmatrix}$$
by using only the anti-commutation relation
$$
\sigma^i\sigma^h+\sigma^h\sigma^i=\{\sigma^i,\sigma^h\}=2\delta^{ih}
$$

([Construction of Pauli Matrices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193022/construction-of-pauli-matrices) Is a similar question, but use the commutators that I want to avoid).

From $(\sigma^i)^2=I$ I found:
$$
\begin{cases}
a^2+bc=1\\
d^2+bc=1\\
b(a+d)=0\\
c(a+d)=0
\end{cases}
$$
and from this:

if $d=a\ne 0$ we have a scalar matrix that commutes with all other matrices, so it cannot be a Pauli matrix.

if $d=-a\ne 0$,  $a=\pm1$ and $b=c=0$ and the matrix has the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
 0& -1
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad \mbox{or}\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\ 
 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which matches $\sigma^3$.

if $d=a=0$ we have $bc=1$, so a matrix of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b\\ 
 1/b& 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but now, how can I prove that the possible values for $b$ are just $-i$ and $1$ ?

Comment: Probably hermiticity.

Comment: I think if you consider all the anti-commutators you can establish that, putting together $\sigma^3$ with matrices $\{\{0, b_1\},\{1/b_1, 0\}\}$ and $\{\{0, b_2\},\{1/b_2, 0\}\}$, you must have either $b_1 = - i b_2$ or $b_1 = i b_2$, and that's as far  as only using anti-commutators will get you.

Comment: You are essentially solving for the Clifford algebra in two Euclidean dimensions. I'm sure there are exhaustive descriptions of its representation around.